# vba code to create a temporary worksheet and have data mail merged to word then the temporary sheet is deleted

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using excel 2010. I would like to see if a new temporary worksheet can be created from 2 other worksheets and data mail merged to an existing word document. Then the temporary worksheet be deleted or maybe saved and reused as a new temporary worksheet. All this in a vba form. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, can be done. What have you tried?

Comment: Im very new to vba excel, I dont know how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

excuse my late reply. The code below creates a new sheet (master) from all existing worksheets, assuming they have the same headings, it then uses that as a source for the mail merge, to delete the sheet would get rid of the source so you can't do that unfortunately, well at least I'm not aware that you can..

```
 Dim wrk As Workbook 'Workbook object - Always good to work with object variables
Dim sht As Worksheet 'Object for handling worksheets in loop
Dim trg As Worksheet 'Master Worksheet
Dim rng As Range 'Range object
Dim colCount As Integer 'Column count in tables in the worksheets
Dim wd As Object 'used for word document
Dim WDoc As Object
Dim strWorkbookName As String
Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook 'Working in active workbook

For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
    If sht.Name = "Master" Then
        MsgBox "There is a worksheet called as 'Master'." & vbCrLf & _
        "Please remove or rename this worksheet since 'Master' would be" & _
        "the name of the result worksheet of this process.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next sht




 'Add new worksheet as the last worksheet
Set trg = wrk.Worksheets.Add(After:=wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count))
 'Rename the new worksheet
trg.Name = "Master"
 'Get column headers from the first worksheet
 'Column count first
Set sht = wrk.Worksheets(1)
colCount = sht.Cells(1, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column
 'Now retrieve headers, no copy&paste needed
With trg.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount)
    .Value = sht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount).Value
     'Set font as bold
    .Font.Bold = True
End With

 'We can start loop
For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
     'If worksheet in loop is the last one, stop execution (it is Master worksheet)
    If sht.Index = wrk.Worksheets.Count Then
        Exit For
    End If
     'Data range in worksheet - starts from second row as first rows are the header rows in all worksheets
    Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount))
     'Put data into the Master worksheet
    trg.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
Next sht
 'Fit the columns in Master worksheet
trg.Columns.AutoFit


On Error Resume Next
Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'creates document
wd.Application.Visible = True 'make word document visible

Set WDoc = wd.Documents.Open("word document location") 'change accordingly

strWorkbookName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName 'declares this workbook as the active workbook to use

WDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
Name:=strWorkbookName, _
ConfirmConversions:=False, _
ReadOnly:=False, _
LinkToSource:=True, _
AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
Revert:=False, _
Format:=0, _
Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Master$`" 'uses temporary created sheet as data source
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will try to see how I can utilize this in my project. You have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

this below should get you started, it will load the data from which ever sheet your using in to word mail merge. you will needs to create a word document and save it- then use that location below.

```
Dim wd As Object
Dim WDoc As Object
Dim strWorkbookName As String

On Error Resume Next
Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wd.Application.Visible = True

Set WDoc = wd.Documents.Open("word location") 'change accordingly

strWorkbookName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName

WDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
    Name:=strWorkbookName, _
   ConfirmConversions:=False, _
ReadOnly:=False, _
LinkToSource:=True, _
AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
Revert:=False, _
Format:=0, _
Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`" 'change to whatever sheet you are using
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Question though, I don't see where it takes the 2 worksheets I need to combine into one. Again I am fairly new but a little knowledgeable in vba. Can you help a little more?

Comment: Hi @George, what is it you want merging, e.g. do they both have the same data and you just want the 2nd sheet adding under where the first sheet ends?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I have a word document that requires data from 2 excel spreadsheets. the data is not the same from the different workbooks. Let me give you the actual project I'm working on. I will get activity sheets  from people. There are 2 type of activity sheets and each type gets the data inputted in the respective worksheet. 3 mail merged word documents get generated for each worksheet. Then a 4th needs to be mail merged with data from both worksheets. So I figured if I create a temporary worksheet combining some data from each sheet, I can mail merge that data.

Comment: Also, Approximately every 4-6 weeks I need to start over with new data so this will be repeated each time.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated. Thanks